# getElementById seems to fail within forms

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have been having problems with getting getElementById working on a specific webpage.  So, I've cut it down the following minimal code.  In this code, first alert() is displayed, but the second one is not, and about the only thing I can guess why is getElementById() is failing.  Any ideas?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Process(X) {
                alert("In Process at A");
                var y = Document.getElementById("YourName").value;
                alert("At B");
            }
        </script>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form onsubmit="Process(getElementById('YourName').value);return false;">
                <label for="name">Your name</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="YourName" id="YourName">

                <input type="submit" value="Do it" />
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Document.getElementById` needs to be `document.getElementById` ... JavaScript is a case-sensitive language so `document` may be a valid keyword but `Document` is not.

Comment: I don't see the need for the down vote - yes, there was a one letter typo, but fixing that typo does not fix the problem.  The real issue was the location of the <script ...> within the file - it apparently needs to be located after what it is referring to.

Comment: The script element is fine where it is.

Comment: @VicFanberg I voted to close this because the issue was the result of a typo. That's not the sort of question whose answer adds any real value to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document.getElementById` fails because `getElementById` is a property of the `document` object not the `Document` object. JS is case-sensitive.

`getElementById('YourName')` fails because `getElementById` is a property of the `document` object and is not a global.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the solution.  Yes, there was a typo (caused by many trials) in "document", but the real solution seems to have been to move the <script ...> below the </div> which you pointed me to by your comment that the document is not global.

Comment: No. 1. The position of the script is irrelevant. 2. You can define a function anywhere. Even if the problem was timing of DOM parsing, it is when you *call* the function that matters. 3. `document` **is** global, I said `getElementById` is **not** global. 5. My point was that you have to call `document.getElementById` because `getElementById` is a property of the `document` object.